# Start @RabbitListener after SpringBoot Application is started

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

We have rabbitMq implementation in our Spring boot application. This is how we are defining the listener. But whenever we start the application AND there are messages in the queue, Consumption of those messages is started before the Application is completely started.

```
@Component
@RabbitListener(queues = "hello")
public class RabbitMqReceiver {
```

I want to start the listener only after the server is up.

Comment: What does mean "after the server is up"?

Answer (score 7):

You can set the `autoStartup` property of your listener to false so that it won't automatically start. You can then start (and later stop) it when you are ready.

Use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` to get a reference to the listener container.

```java
@RabbitListener(id = "foo". ..., autoStartup = "false")

...

@Autowired
RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

...

registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start();
```

See [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#_reference).

> Container Management
>   Containers created for annotations are not registered with the application context. You can obtain a collection of all containers by invoking `getListenerContainers()` on the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean. You can then iterate over this collection, for example, to stop or start all containers or invoke the Lifecycle methods on the registry itself, which will invoke the operations on each container.
>
> You can also get a reference to an individual container by using its id, using getListenerContainer(String id) — for example, `registry.getListenerContainer("multi")` for the container created by the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the Component is initiated you don't need to process the messages if you don't want, you can set a flag to wait until the app is initialized to start processing then:

https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring